# How to deallocate unused SKScene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, dealloc, skscene

I have a SKScene object setup in GameViewController. I implemented `dealloc` into the SKScene subclass as follow:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"Dealloc: %@", self);
}
```

Now I want to present another view controller on top of GameViewController. I used storyboard segue to do this. But after the new view controller is presented, I never received the SKScene dealloc. It got stuck in the memory. My app starts to freeze after a few minute due to low memory. How can I dealloc the scene after presenting the new view controller.

Comment: @user3351949 I did this: `SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view; [skView presentScene:nil];` does not work.

Comment: @user3351949 Now I did this: `SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    GameScene *scene = (GameScene *)skView.scene;
    [skView presentScene:nil];
    scene = nil;` Still doesn't work

Comment: You're presenting a ViewController ontop of another ViewController.... the previous VC doesn't get dealloc'ed when you present the next VC .....  There's a navigation stack that you're creating here which has a reference to everything in the stack. If what you present is presented while removing the previous VC from the stack... then you're VC and it's respective view (the SKView) will be dealloc'ed as long as nothing else contains a strong reference to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to deallocate you `SKScene` instance -> you Should Eliminate every pointer that retains it -> then ARC will automagically release it.

Simply call the `[skView presentScene:nil];` method which also will remove the `SCScene` and deallocate it by setting `SKView.scene` property to nil.

```
SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view; 
GameScene *scene = (GameScene *)skView.scene; 

for(SKNode * child in scene.children)
{
    [child removeAllActions];
}
[scene removeAllChildren];
[scene removeAllActions];
[skView presentScene:nil];
```

**Note** Normally you don't have to remove everything from the `SKScene` if your memory is managed right just call `[skView presentScene:nil];` method and **ARC** will take care of it.

Apparently you had something inside the `SKScene` that retained it. 
So by removing everything from it, we eliminated the retain cycle.

**This solution will not always work, it will work only if one of the `SKActions` or `SKNodes` are retaining the `SKScene` which were the issue in your case, However your `SKScene` could be retained from somewhere else and this answer wouldn't really help you**

Comment: I called `[scene removeFromParent];`, still doesn't work.

Comment: The `NSLog` to the `dealloc` method on GameScene still isn't called for some reason. The memory doesn't seems to be released.

Comment: Check maybe you have a strong pointer cycle -> this method should work actually.

Comment: Oh maybe you still have some actions ?
try to remove all actions I will post a code snippet.
Please try it.
If it doesn't work then I suggest to profile in Instruments using Allocations

Comment: I used `[scene removeAllAction];` still doesn't work, maybe there are a pointer in Apple's private API preventing the scene from deallocating

Comment: 'scene removeAllActions' will remove actions from the scene but not its children 'SKNodes' but I will add it to my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103403/discussion-between-tom-shen-and-user3351949).

Comment: Just doing [skView presentScene:nil]; should be enough; if the view is the only holder; if you are using ARC. Because when you remove the scene from from who ever is using it, it should deallocate and all its members too.

Comment: @StackUnderflow Apparently it wasn't the case.

Comment: @user3351949 Calling scene's removeFromParent doesn't make sense and it has no effect due to fact that scene is a root node, and its parent property is always set to nil.

Comment: Related to `presentScene:nil` part. It's not needed at all, if the memory is managed correctly, because after regular scene's transition, if there is no strong reference cycles, everything will be deallocated correctly. But if  there is a strong reference cycle (eg. you have a block defined as property of the scene, but block captures self inside its body), scene's dealloc won't be called, even if you do `presentScene:nil`, and you will have a leak on every subsequent transition. So, no need for `presentScene:nil` in situations like this.

Comment: @Whirlwind No `removeFromParent` and no `presentScene:nil` ?
Then how the `SKScene` will invalidate ?

Comment: @user3351949 If memory is managed correctly, scene will be deallocated automatically. Means, if there is no strong reference cycles similar to what I've described in my last comment (where object  keeps a strong reference to the scene, but the scene keeps strong reference back to that object etc..) You don't have to set scene to nil explicitly...ARC will do that for you automatically, right after there is no strong references pointing to the scene.

Comment: @Whirlwind If I understand correctly: `SKScene` is subclass of `SKNode`
then presenting the `SKScene` on `SKView` will add the `SKScene` to the `SKView`'s `children` array -  so `SKView` will retain the `SKScene` -- From what I am understanding one of those methods should be called in order to Free the `SKScene` (remove the `SKScene` from the `SKView.children`)-- Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Whirlwind `SKView's` `scene` property and not it's `children` apparently
But it is the same general idea

Comment: @user3351949 Yeah, SKView doesn't have children array property. It has the scene property...So, when you say presentScene:scene, the new scene will immediately replace the current scene . And if memory is managed correctly, the old scene will be deallocated correctly (old scene's dealloc will be executed). But if there is a retain cycle which keeps the old scene alive,  the old scene will not be removed from memory.

Comment: @Whirlwind Yeah I got it - And I have edited the answer accordingly, thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @Whirlwind Guess I am done with edits -> Could you review please?

Comment: @user3351949  Option 1 - doesn't make sense, you can't remove a scene from its parent, because scene can't have a parent... Scene is a root node in SpriteKit's node's tree. So this action has no effect. Option 2 (`presentScene:nil`) - I've posted a comment about this already :) It is not needed in order to make a transition to another scene, and it will not help if something else retaining the old scene(transition will work, but you will have a leak).

Comment: One way to fight against strong ref. cycles is to use weak references where is appropriate. Read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW3). (Avoid Strong Reference Cycles part).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103433/discussion-between-whirlwind-and-user3351949).